# TextInputDialog assign KeyEvent handler to editor

Tags: java, javafx

I wanted to use a standard `TextInputDialog` to enable the user to enter a `Price` (a dollar value) which will then be applied to all selected rows of a `TableView` (after conversion).

According to the API the `getEditor()` method of `TextInputDialog` returns the `TextField` used in the `Dialog`. When I attempted to assign a `KeyEvent` handler to the editor (`TextField`) I received a compiler error on `tField.setOnKeyPressed` in NetBeans:

```
"incomaptible types < anonymous EventHandler<java.awt.event.KeyEvent>> cannot be converted to EventHandler<?, super javafx.Scene.Input.KeyEvent>>
type argument T is a type-variable:
T extends Event declared in interface EventHandler.
```

Basic code is:

```
    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Set PRICE per kg.");
    dialog.setContentText("Price per kg:");

    // Configure the EDITOR.
    TextField tField = dialog.getEditor();        
    tField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) 
        {
            String character = ke.getCharacter();
            String text = ke.getText();

            if ( !LM_Utility.isNumberKeyValid(text, character, 99.99) )
                ke.consume();                
        }
    });
```

where the utility function I have used effectively in other places is:

```
public static Boolean isNumberKeyValid(String text, String character, Double maxValue)
{
    Boolean valid = Boolean.FALSE;
    String fullText = text + character;
    Double fullNumber = Double.valueOf(fullText);

     if ( ( character.matches("\\d")  || character.equals(".") ) && ( fullNumber <= maxValue ) )
          valid = Boolean.TRUE;

  return valid;  

}
```

Comment: There is no reason to use the wrapper class `Boolean` here. You can use primitive `boolean`, this is more efficient. Same for `Double`

Comment: Thank you. Changing the import, fixed the compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the compile error, you are using the Swing `KeyEvent` type instead of the JavaFX one. Just fix your imports.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the import, fixed the compiler error. However, I have an unexpected problem with the consume() method. If maxValue is 99.99 and I enter 1, and then 2, it accepts both of these characters as "valid", When I then enter 3, it determines that it is invalid, and ke.consume() is executed, and 3 appears in the Textfield. I want to reject values "out of range" 0 to maxValue (99.99).